# Parse Date dynamically

Tags: date, go

I have a case in which I can have both **Date** alone or with **Date + Time Zone** . So when I parse it with **TimeZone** like this

```
dateString := "2021-03-11T00:00:00Z"
time1, _ := time.Parse(time.RFC3339,dateString);
   
fmt.Println(time1);
```

It gives accurate answer but when I dynamically It gets `Date` like

```
dateString := "2021-03-11"
time1, _ := time.Parse(time.RFC3339,dateString);
   
fmt.Println(time1);   //gives this 0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC
```

while In both cases I just want date like this  **"2021-03-11"**. what is best way to achieve this

Comment: You parse with `time.RFC3339` and check for parsing error. If an error happened - you try to parse it second time using the different format. And an advice: **never** ignore returned errors in go

Comment: @zerkms working  .yes newbie here will not ignore return errors . thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To parse just the date, you can use "2006-01-02" as the layout to `time.Parse`.

See [the official docs](https://pkg.go.dev/time#pkg-constants) for how these layouts are handled and what `time.Parse` expects.

As @zerkms says in a comment, if you check the error from `time.Parse` you'll know whether it succeeded or not, so you can try something else. Rough code sketch:

```
dateString := "2021-03-11"
time1, err := time.Parse(time.RFC3339, dateString)
if err != nil {
    time1, err = time.Parse("2006-01-02", dateString)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("cannot parse using either layout:", err)
    }
}

fmt.Println(time1)
```

In real life I'd probably wrap it in a function that tries parsing both ways before it gives up and returns an error.